# Remove duplicates from input without use of any data structures

Tags: c++, algorithm

*Disclaimer*: This question is more of a challenge, and the post is also quite long. Read only in free time!

### The Problem:

Basically, suppose there is a single line of integer inputs:

```
32352\n     // assuming single digits only and no spaces for simplification
```

We have to remove duplicates from the inputs, and then display them. So, output should be:

```
After removing duplicates: 2, 3, 5      // display them in any order
```

However, there is a catch:

- *Do not use **any** <s>data structures</s> containers.*

***Edit***: I believe containers are what I meant ([thanks Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59327362/9414470)!).

So, my question is: *What is the error in my implementation, and is there another (better) way to do it?*

### My thought process:

Since we are not allowed use of any data structure, we cannot store the inputs (I think?).
However, since it is already stored in memory on input, that is not a problem.

More of a problem is removing the duplicates. We will have to manipulate the input stream.

The first thing that struck me is that we can sort the inputs. That is,

```
32352
```

becomes:

```
22335
```

And now, simply print the first element of each range.
Working on this idea, I came across the [`std::cin.get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) and [`std::cin.putback()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/putback/) methods, both accepting a `char`.

I also realized I would have to use recursion.

And hence, the code becomes (I have used [insertion sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/)):

### The Code:

The `sort()` function is where the error is. It uses a running `index` ala arrays, and this is used to uniquely identify each element.

In each iteration, the `index_of_element` element is found and selected, and we determine where in the remaining (virtual) array, we need to place it. For example, if in our original input:

```
32352    // S = sorted subarray
SU--U    // U = unsorted subarray
```

, the first `2` is selected, we "shift" `3` (as `3 < 2`).
Now, there are no more elements left to shift, we "place" `2`.
The result should become:

```
23352
SSU-U
```

The (buggy) implementation:

```cpp
bool sort(int index_of_element, int index = 0, char prev_element = 0)
{
    static char element;
    char digit;
    // retrieve an element from memory
    std::cin.get(digit);
    // If not end of input
    if(digit != '\n')
    {
        // store the element for comparision
        if(index == index_of_element)
        {
            element = digit;
        }
        // continue forward until '\n'
        bool result = sort(index_of_element, index + 1, digit);
        // if we are in sorted subarray
        if(index <= index_of_element)
        {
            // If element belongs here(also if this is first element(prev_element is 0)), place it
            if(element > prev_element)
            {
                digit = element;
                // Signal that element has been placed
                element = 0;
            }
            // Else, if element not already placed, we need to shift elements
            else if(element != 0)
            {
                // Place the previous element here
                digit = prev_element;
            }
        }
        // Put it back in memory
        std::cin.putback(digit);
        // And return the result
        return result;
    }
    // Which is generated here when end of input is reached
    else
    {
        // If sorted all elements, break loop
        if(index_of_element == index)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Else, continue sorting
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

(A wall of code, but I didn't want to skip anything relevant), and it should be used as:

```cpp
...
int index_of_element = 0;
while(sort(index_of_element++));
...
```

The display function is ready, and it works properly.
What I do know is that it gets stuck in an infinite loop and the values are lost.
What is going wrong?

And should I add the output (The post is already very long)?

Comment: What is `any data structures`? Is that refereing to classes? You are passing a single `char` to `sort` which can't be right.

Comment: You are using `std::cin` as a datastructure

Comment: @super It was said not to use any arrays, vectors, stacks, queues etc and neither our own implementations of it. I simplified the condition.

Comment: @Caleth Oh? it is? ** face palm ** Any ideas then? It might not be possible then, I think.

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't understand. I am using the result as a terminating condition for the outer loop. Could you please be a little clearer (a noob here).

Comment: Without a precise definition of what the restriction is, it's problematic. You can call the function call stack a data structure

Comment: @Caleth Well, the asker specifically said that recursion was an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with only function objects, in a single pass.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <functional>

void print_unique_ints(std::istream & in, std::ostream & out, std::function<bool(int)> unseen) {
    for (int i; in >> i;) {
        if (unseen(i)) {
            out << i << ' ';
            print_unique_ints(in, out, [&](int j){ return (i != j) && unseen(j); });
            return; // not actually needed, previous call only ends when input is exhausted
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    print_unique_ints(std::cin, std::cout, [](int){ return true; });
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfc051409f494cca)

Each call to `print_unique_ints` skips previously seen ints, prints the unseen int, and adds to the filter

Substituting values for variables; and function calls for expressions; in the first call

```
    for (int i; in >> i;) { // i = 3
        if (true) {
            out << 3 << ' ';
            print_unique_ints(...) // see below
        }
    }
```

The second

```
    for (int i; in >> i;) { // i = 2
        if ((3 != i) && true) {
            out << 2 << ' ';
            print_unique_ints(...) // see below
        }
    }
```

The third

```
    for (int i; in >> i;) { // i = 3, 5
        if ((2 != i) && (3 != i) && true) { // skips over the 3
            out << 5 << ' ';
            print_unique_ints(...) // see below
        }
    }
```

The forth

```
    for (int i; in >> i;) { // i = 2
        if ((5 != i) && (2 != i) && (3 != i) && true) { // skips the 2 and finds the end of input
        }
    }
```

Note that `&& true` never changes the result in the `if`

Comment: Oh my... I will have to comprehend this. What is this technique called? And could you also include some explanation? That would make this a great answer!

Comment: I don't know if it has a name. I'll try to improve the explanation

Comment: @DanielJour I'd call it a list, but yes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you don't put the newline back into the stream, while your code assumes that it will be there.
That is, after your first pass, `digit != '\n'` is always true.

Put the newline back into the stream, or break when you've reached the true end-of-stream.

(There could also be problems with (ab)using `std::cin` like this, but I'm not sure, and that's another matter anyway.)

Comment: Yes, this is it! I was reading the `'\n'` at the end, but no one was putting it back, as the condition `digit != '\n'` was false. Added it in the `else` part, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A variation of bitset (or mask) implem...using the commutative property of multiplication

Take a function `f` which maps every digit to a unique prime `p_i`

```
0 1 2 3 4 5  6  7  8  9
2,3,5,7,9,11,13,17,19,23
```

If all numbers are found the total amount to `N=2*3*5*7*9*11*13*17*19*23=2007835830`

Consume `cin` as `c`, if `f(c)` divides `N`, print `c` and update `N /= f(c)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int f(char c){
  if(c=='0') return 2;
  if(c=='1') return 3;
  if(c=='2') return 5;
  if(c=='3') return 7;
  if(c=='4') return 9;
  if(c=='5') return 11;
  if(c=='6') return 13;
  if(c=='7') return 17;
  if(c=='8') return 19;
  if(c=='9') return 23;
}
int main() {
  std::istringstream in("2 2 2 3 5");
  int N = 2007835830;
  char c;
  while(in >> c){
    if(c=='\n') break;
    int p_i = f(c);
    if(N % p_i == 0){
      N = N/p_i;
      std::cout<<c<<" ";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even more interestingly, `2007835830` lies _just_ inside the integer bounds.

Comment: Answer works, so +1. But can it be extended to work for multi-digit integral input? Also, missing a `return 0;`

Comment: You have found the answer yourself! it will not since we will need more prime numbers and the total will (at some point) overflow the integer bound. This is just using dirtyly the fact that we have single digits

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that this phrase

> Remove duplicates from input without use of any data structures

means that you shall not use any container like for example `std::string` or an ordinary array.

The assignment is not simple for a beginner.

Here are my five cents.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T remove_duplicates( T n )
{
    static_assert ( std::is_integral<T>::value );

    const T Base = 10;

    T result = n % Base;  

    for ( T multiplier = 1; n /= Base; )
    {
        T digit = n % Base;

        T tmp = result;

        bool unique = true;
        while ( ( unique = tmp % Base != digit ) && ( tmp /= Base ) );

        if ( unique )
        {
            multiplier *= Base;
            result = digit == 0 ? result * multiplier + digit
                                : digit * multiplier + result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    for ( int n : { 0, 1, 10, 101, 100, 10203, -1, -10, -101, -100, - 10203 } )
    {
        std::cout << n << ": " << remove_duplicates( n ) << '\n';
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0: 0
1: 1
10: 10
101: 10
100: 10
10203: 1230
-1: -1
-10: -10
-101: -10
-100: -10
-10203: -1230
```

That is you are building a new number from the source number by checking whether the new number already contains a digit from the source number.

The function can work with any integer type signed or unsigned. It correctly processes digits equal to 0.

Comment: Wait, you are removing duplicates (digits) from _each number_ in the stream?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar According to the description if for example the number 32352 was entered then duplicate digits must be removed.

Comment: Well, yes. However, it was a simplification for `3 2 3 5 2`, or even `12 56 32 12 6 12`. Basically, there are several separate numbers in a single line, and I want to remove duplicates from them.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar DO you need to remove duplicate numbers in the input stream or duplicate digits in each number in the stream?

Comment: I wanted to remove duplicate numbers in the input stream. However, I had to simplify the problem and remove useless code( to calculate the numbers digit by digit and handle spaces, remember that `get` and `putback` take `char`s ). Therefore, any solution to either of "remove duplicate numbers from stream" or "remove duplicate digits from a number" suffice, though the first one will be preferred.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar The assignment does not make any sense because the stream buffer is a kind of a container. You can not fp the task without a container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204248/discussion-between-jaideep-shekhar-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @JaideepShekhar I am sorry I do not spend my time in chats.

Comment: It is sufficient to say that this answer can be adapted to solve both my problems. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

> It was said not to use any arrays, vectors, stacks, queues etc and neither our own implementations of it. I simplified the condition.

Well I've got bad news for you; this is not possible.

Given an input of length N you will need to   somehow remember the previous N - 1 values to decide whether to print the Nth value or not. This is not possible with constant space.

So you need *some* data structure.

Now ...

> Since we are not allowed use of any data structure, we cannot store the inputs (I think?).
>   However, **since it is already stored in memory on input**, that is not a problem.

So let's assume the existence of a (mutable) array of length N, containing the input values. Now we can solve this without using additional storage / data structures:

1. Select some value as special value
2. Iterate over the numbers until you find a value which is not that special value. print that value. Write the special value to the array where you found the value you just printed. finish iterating over the numbers, overwritte each occurrence of the just printed value with the special value.
3. repeat (from 2) until the input consists only of special values.

You just need to think about a way to handle the case where the special value was present in the input from the start.

Comment: I suppose [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) or [`std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) could be used.

Comment: doesn't matter which value you use; if you want it to be correct you need to handle the case of it being in the initial input. You need an additional pass for this.

Comment: ah, no, there's a way without additional pass: just use the first value